# Use local command prompt on foreign computer

Tags: linux, node.js, command, installation

I'm working with a Linux embedded system which is heavily limited in command prompts (has no commands to install new software). I've been trying to install in all kinds of ways but always miss one or two commands to finish installing `nodejs`.

This problem made me wonder if there's is anyway to **borrow commands** from the computer I have connected to the embedded system.

i.e. could I connect to the embedded system in a way that lets me use the commands from my local system temporarily on the embedded system to install nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot borrow commands. Either you can install tools in your local or the remote machine if you have proper permissions

Comment: So is there anyway to install through one computer and transfer installation over to the embedded system?

Comment: You can copy the files like tar,zip etc.. But if it is a installer file  it has to be installed separately in that machine